# SQL: Fill missing dates for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, calendar

I want to fill missing dates in my db, yet I have different groups. The new cells should be filled with the value of latest date for each material number
This is how my `database` looks like now:

```
Date [YYYY-MM-DD]   Materialnumber            Amount
2019-01-01            X                        5
2019-01-15            X                        7
2019-01-20            X                        2
2019-02-02            X                        8
2019-01-03            Y                        756
2019-01-18            Y                        750
2019-02-22            Y                        720
2019-03-05            Y                        820
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Date [YYYY-MM-DD]   Materialnumber            Amount
2019-01-01            X                        5
2019-01-02            X                        5
2019-01-03            X                        5
2019-01-04            X                        5
                     ...
2019-01-15            X                        7
2019-01-16            X                        7
2019-01-17            X                        7
                     ...
2019-01-01            Y                        756
2019-01-02            Y                        756
2019-01-03            Y                        756
                     ...
2019-01-18            Y                        750
2019-01-19            Y                        750
                     ...
```

I created a `calendar` table by doing:

```
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20190101' as date) AS [Date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20191231'
)
SELECT [date] 
KSH_calendar 
FROM CTE_DatesTable
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I've tried this:

```
   select c.[Date]
    ,b.Materialnumber
    ,b.Amount
    from KSH_calendar as c
    left join database as b on c.[Date] = b.[MKPF_CPUDT]
```

But this does'nt lead me to the expected result. Not even speaking about getting the latest value.
Does anyone has some ideas/links for me to get closer to the result?

Using a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (Version ID 14)

Kind regards,

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using a MS SQL Server 2017 (Version ID 14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows, then bring in the values.  In this case `OUTER APPLY` might be the simplest solution:

```
select c.[Date], m.Materialnumber, d.Amount
from KSH_calendar c cross join
     (select distinct d.Materialnumber
      from database d
     ) m outer apply
     (select top (1) d.*
      from database d
      where d.Materialnumber = m.Materialnumber and
            c.date <= d.MKPF_CPUDT
      order by d.date desc
     ) d;
```

If you have a lot of dates, then an index on `database(materialnumber, MKPF_CPUDT)` will help.  But there are alternative methods that are a little more complicated.  I would recommend that you ask another question if performance is an issue.

Comment: In fact, your idea helped me a lot.

I created a a cross join table of the calendar date with the materialnumber. and then a joined the database to it.

But the performance is horrible... even for my small dataset. 

Still, thanks

Comment: @hergo.1 . . . The probably is probably filling in the data for the missing dates. If the index doesn't help, then ask another question.